# Reinforcement Learning Issues in Space Cadet 3D-Pinball Game

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am currently working on a reinforcement learning project for the Space Cadet 3D-Pinball game.

I have constructed a neural network using a simple Fully Connected Layer with the DQN method.

Currently, I am using 4 state inputs:

- Ball's x-coordinate
- Ball's y-coordinate
- Difference in ball's x-coordinate between the previous frame and current frame (old_x - x)
- Difference in ball's y-coordinate between the previous frame and current frame (old_y - y)

The rewards are as follows:

- Positive reward of score gain * 0.001
- Negative reward of -1 if the ball doesn't move within the range of flipper activity (where it can be hit)
- Negative reward of -10 when a life is lost

The actions are as follows:

- 0: Release all keys
- 1: Press left flipper key
- 2: Release left flipper key
- 3: Press right flipper key
- 4: Release right flipper key

With these settings, I proceeded with the episode, and the flipper's response when the ball is close is observed.

[3D-Pinball Agent GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkuG9.gif)

As can be seen at the end of the GIF file, there is a persistent tendency to restrict the movement of the ball by keeping the flippers pressed.

I tried removing actions 2 and 4 and changed the implementation to press and release the flipper key for a certain period.

> When the press and release speed was short (e.g. 50ms),
> it still showed a behavior of continuously activating a specific flipper, restricting the movement of the ball.

> When the press and release speed was a bit longer (e.g. 200ms),
> there is a problem of significant frame processing speed reduction.

This is the main cause of delaying learning in various aspects at the moment,
and I would like to hear various solutions to this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Adjusting the reward function to discourage this kind of trapping behavior? Another solution could be to modify our state function to add some kind of new variable, such position and velocity of the flippers?

Comment: @JishanShaikh Thank you for your opinion.
Adjusting the reward function to give negative rewards when the ball is not moving didn't solve the current behavior issue. Currently, I have obtained the edge coordinates of both flippers using openCV.
If I were to add a new state variable, would it be possible to use the movement of the edge coordinates of the flippers for each frame as the state value?
I'm concerned because there are many coordinates that represent the edges.

Comment: It is possible to use the movement of the edge coordinates, but to overcome the issue of "too many coordinates (dimensionality reduction)", we can use a summary (indirect) metric (e.g., mean/median/deviation/or some sort of combination)  of the edge coordinates. For each frame, for example, you can use `np.mean(edge_coordinates[:, 0])` for x and `np.mean(edge_coordinates[:, 1])`.

Comment: @JishanShaikh Thank you. I will proceed with the method you mentioned.